# Geonode-project not assuming changes in css

Tags: css, django, collectstatic

I created a Geonode project following the instructions of geonode-project GitHub repo.

After running the instance for development using the respective docker-compose files I tried to apply changes to site_index.html and site_base.css files.

The changes on the html file are ok however the css changes are not assumed, only if I run the collectstatic command.

Since I'm running it in dev I was expecting that the collectstatic would not be necessary.

I tried to add the volume `-./my_geonode/static/css:/mnt/volumes/statics/static/css` in the django service on the docker-compose.development.override.yml file but even so t doesn't work. When I enter in the django container and open the file/mnt/volumes/statics/static/css/site_base.css my change is there though.

Doing developments and run the collectstatic at every css change is annoying. Am I doing something wrong? Please help.

Thanks